# How to setup a header in a pivot (CrossTab) report (MS Report Designer)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have the following table which I'd like to turn into a report:

```
ClientGroup | Product | Client | Quantity
-----------------------------------------
  Gr1       | P1      | C1     | 10
  Gr1       | P1      | C2     | 20
  Gr1       | P1      | C3     | 30
  Gr1       | P2      | C1     | 40
  Gr1       | P2      | C2     | 50
  Gr1       | P2      | C3     | 60
  Gr2       | P1      | C4     | 70
  Gr2       | P1      | C5     | 80
  Gr2       | P1      | C6     | 90
  Gr2       | P2      | C4     | 100
  Gr2       | P2      | C5     | 110
  Gr2       | P2      | C6     | 120
```

The report would have the following layout:

```
--------------------
|        G1        |
--------------------
Client | P1  | P2  |
--------------------
C1     | 10  | 40  |
C2     | 20  | 50  |
C3     | 30  | 60  |
--------------------
Total  | 60  |150  |
--------------------
|        G2        |
--------------------
Client | P1  | P2  |
--------------------
C4     | 70  | 100 |
C5     | 80  | 110 |
C5     | 90  | 120 |
--------------------
Total  | 240 | 330 |
--------------------
```

What I'm doing is to create a Matrix, add a row group on ClientGroup, a sub group row on Client, a column group on Product with Quantity as detail. In the designer it looks somewhat like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
|  ClientGroup  | Client   | [Product]      |
---------------------------------------------
| [ClientGroup] | [Client] | Sum([Quantity])|
---------------------------------------------
```

I then hide the ClientGroup column and it seems I'm almost there. What I can't figure out is how to have a header over the columns Client and [Product] displaying the current ClientGroup.

Is it possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close:

- Set the Headings row to be hidden.
- Right-click the `[Client]` cell and select Insert Row > Outside Group - Above, twice.
- Copy `[ClientGroup]` into the left-hand cell on the first new row, and set the BorderStyle-Right of the cell to be None.
- Select the right-hand cell on the first new row, and set the BorderStyle-Left and -Right of the cell to be None.
- Copy the heading `Client` into the left-hand cell on the second new row.
- Copy `[Product]` into the right-hand cell on the second new row.

Your report should look something like this in the designer:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  ClientGroup  | Client        | [Product]      |
--------------------------------------------------
| [ClientGroup] | [ClientGroup] |                |
|               |---------------------------------
|               | Client        | [Product]      |
|               |---------------------------------
|               | [Client]      | Sum([Quantity])|
--------------------------------------------------
```

If you preview it, the results should be pretty close to the desired layout.